# How to change the src of multiple images at once depending on selected list item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a selection of images (and thumbnails) of a car as part of my site. There are four different colours, and a selection list to choose a colour. I want to be able to choose a different colour on the list such that 4 of the 6 images on display change so they are of a different colour.

I have researched this and found methods that can switch images, but no matter what I do I can only change them to the same image, I can't seem to use multiple srcs.
Code for the images and selection list attached:

```
<ul class="slides">
            <li data-thumb="images/audi/red/au.jpg" name="audi">
                <div class="thumb-image"> <img src="images/audi/red/au.jpg" data-imagezoom="true" class="img-responsive" name="audi"> </div>
            </li>
            <li data-thumb="images/audi/red/au1.jpg" name="audi1">
                 <div class="thumb-image"> <img src="images/audi/red/au1.jpg" data-imagezoom="true" class="img-responsive" name="audi1"> </div>
            </li>
            <li data-thumb="images/audi/red/au2.jpg" name="audi2">
               <div class="thumb-image"> <img src="images/audi/red/au2.jpg" data-imagezoom="true" class="img-responsive" name="audi2"> </div>
            </li> 
             <li data-thumb="images/audi/red/au3.jpg" name="audi3">
               <div class="thumb-image"> <img src="images/audi/red/au3.jpg" data-imagezoom="true" class="img-responsive" name="audi3"> </div>
            </li>
             <li data-thumb="images/audi/au4.jpg">
               <div class="thumb-image"> <img src="images/audi/au4.jpg" data-imagezoom="true" class="img-responsive"> </div>
            </li>
            <li data-thumb="images/audi/au4a.jpg">
               <div class="thumb-image"> <img src="images/audi/au4a.jpg" data-imagezoom="true" class="img-responsive"> </div>
            </li>
          </ul>
<li>Select a Colour:
    <select name="car-colour" id="car-colour">
    <option value="red">Red</option>
    <option value="white">White</option>
    <option value="black">Black</option>
    <option value="blue">Blue</option>
</select></li>
```

Comment: Give a unique `id` for each `<img>` element to make identifiable then use the jQuery `$('#car-colour').change(function(){ $('#IMG-ID-HERE').attr('src', 'NEW-IMAGE-SRC'); });` to change that image's id as you wish.

Comment: Is it four random images in the list or is it only the four upper images?

Comment: @Zorken17 - it's just the four upper images, the other 2 can stay the same as they are the interior of the car.

Comment: Does you images are located in their respective color named directories?

Comment: @RuslanAbuzant how would you make this work with the selection list?

Comment: @JyothiBabuAraja yes, they're all organized as images/audi/colour/au.jpg, au1.jpg, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you will keep you URL  structure as is, you can do something like this:

```js
$( "#car-colour" ).change(function() {
self=$(this);
targets=$('.slides li').each(function() {
if($(this).index()<4) {

dthumb=$(this).data('thumb').split('/');

dthumb[2]=self.val();
final=dthumb.join('/');
$(this).attr('data-thumb',final);
$(this).find('img').attr('src',final);
}
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="slides">
            <li data-thumb="images/audi/red/au.jpg" name="audi">
                <div class="thumb-image"> <img src="images/audi/red/au.jpg" data-imagezoom="true" class="img-responsive" name="audi"> </div>
            </li>
            <li data-thumb="images/audi/red/au1.jpg" name="audi1">
                 <div class="thumb-image"> <img src="images/audi/red/au1.jpg" data-imagezoom="true" class="img-responsive" name="audi1"> </div>
            </li>
            <li data-thumb="images/audi/red/au2.jpg" name="audi2">
               <div class="thumb-image"> <img src="images/audi/red/au2.jpg" data-imagezoom="true" class="img-responsive" name="audi2"> </div>
            </li> 
             <li data-thumb="images/audi/red/au3.jpg" name="audi3">
               <div class="thumb-image"> <img src="images/audi/red/au3.jpg" data-imagezoom="true" class="img-responsive" name="audi3"> </div>
            </li>
             <li data-thumb="images/audi/au4.jpg">
               <div class="thumb-image"> <img src="images/audi/au4.jpg" data-imagezoom="true" class="img-responsive"> </div>
            </li>
            <li data-thumb="images/audi/au4a.jpg">
               <div class="thumb-image"> <img src="images/audi/au4a.jpg" data-imagezoom="true" class="img-responsive"> </div>
            </li>
          </ul>
<li>Select a Colour:
    <select name="car-colour" id="car-colour">
    <option value="red">Red</option>
    <option value="white">White</option>
    <option value="black">Black</option>
    <option value="blue">Blue</option>
      </select></li>
```

Please check generated HTML. If your images folder will have color names, this should work.

Comment: This works great, thanks. The only problem I should've mentioned is that the thumbnails should change too, any ideas?

Comment: @jcrossley, np, glad to help.And thumbnails are in other HTML section? You can apply similar logic to them...

Comment: @Landaida, my code changes img src and data-thumb, too? Can't see the difference? Btw, they are the same in provided html, so, not sure what OP means by thumbs changing, actually...

Comment: @sinisake sorry only I replied the first comment jcrossley I don't see your comment, sorry

Comment: @Landaida, np, waiting for clarification from jcrossley, but i am sure he will find the way... ;)

Comment: @sinisake when I choose a colour the actual slide images change to match, but the thumbnails remain red...

Comment: @jcrossley, and where you define thumbnails src? It is not in data-thumbs? Are last two images thumbs? Sorry, little misunderstanding here, it seems. :)

Comment: If thumbs are in another HTML section (which is the case, obviously), please just provide that HTML code, and we can solve it easily.

Comment: @jcrossley, actually, not sure what is problem, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

[Download jQuery](https://jquery.com/download/) and Add jQuery in your folder and add the code in your html:

```
<script src="jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
```

You can use jQuery for it and use one function `.attr`, but first, give a unique ID for all option value and you can put all images in one class:
Give a unique ID for all:

```
 <li>Select a Colour:
        <select id="picID">
        <option value="red" selected>Red</option>
        <option value="white">White</option>
        <option value="black">Black</option>
        <option value="blue">Blue</option>
        </select></li>
```

and add all images in one class (you can use local images to):

```
  var picList = [
"images/1.jpg",
"images/2.jpg",
"images/3.jpg",
 ];
```

and after:

```
$('#car-colour').change(function () {
    var val = parseInt($('#picID').val());
    $('img').attr("src",picList[val]);
});
```

Reference [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_attr.asp).

Answer (score 0):

As you said that you maintain proper directory structure for colors. This might work for you.

```js
$("#car-colour").change(function(){
  var color = $(this).val().trim();
  $("li").each(function(index){
    if(index > 3) return;
    var arr = $(this).attr('data-thumb').trim().split('/');
    arr.splice(2,1, color);
    var newImgSrc = arr.join('/');
    $(this).attr('data-thumb', newImgSrc);
    $(this).find('img').attr('src', newImgSrc);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="slides">
  <li data-thumb="images/audi/red/au.jpg" name="audi">
    <div class="thumb-image">
      <img src="images/audi/red/au.jpg" data-imagezoom="true" class="img-responsive" name="audi">
    </div>
  </li>
  <li data-thumb="images/audi/red/au1.jpg" name="audi1">
    <div class="thumb-image">
      <img src="images/audi/red/au1.jpg" data-imagezoom="true" class="img-responsive" name="audi1">
    </div>
  </li>
  <li data-thumb="images/audi/red/au2.jpg" name="audi2">
    <div class="thumb-image">
      <img src="images/audi/red/au2.jpg" data-imagezoom="true" class="img-responsive" name="audi2">
    </div>
  </li>
  <li data-thumb="images/audi/red/au3.jpg" name="audi3">
    <div class="thumb-image">
      <img src="images/audi/red/au3.jpg" data-imagezoom="true" class="img-responsive" name="audi3">
    </div>
  </li>
  <li data-thumb="images/audi/au4.jpg">
    <div class="thumb-image">
      <img src="images/audi/au4.jpg" data-imagezoom="true" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
  </li>
  <li data-thumb="images/audi/au4a.jpg">
    <div class="thumb-image">
      <img src="images/audi/au4a.jpg" data-imagezoom="true" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
<li>Select a Colour:
  <select name="car-colour" id="car-colour">
    <option value="red">Red</option>
    <option value="white">White</option>
    <option value="black">Black</option>
    <option value="blue">Blue</option>
  </select>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```js
$(document).ready(()=>{
    $('#car-colour').change(function () {
        let newColor = this[this.selectedIndex].value;
        $('img').attr('src', (index, src)=>{
          return src.replace(/red|white|black|blue/gi, newColor);
        })
        $('li[data-thumb*=images]').attr('data-thumb', (index, src)=>{
          return src.replace(/red|white|black|blue/gi, newColor);
        })
    })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="slides">
            <li data-thumb="images/audi/red/au.jpg" name="audi">
                <div class="thumb-image"> <img src="images/audi/red/au.jpg" data-imagezoom="true" class="img-responsive" name="audi"> </div>
            </li>
            <li data-thumb="images/audi/red/au1.jpg" name="audi1">
                 <div class="thumb-image"> <img src="images/audi/red/au1.jpg" data-imagezoom="true" class="img-responsive" name="audi1"> </div>
            </li>
            <li data-thumb="images/audi/red/au2.jpg" name="audi2">
               <div class="thumb-image"> <img src="images/audi/red/au2.jpg" data-imagezoom="true" class="img-responsive" name="audi2"> </div>
            </li> 
             <li data-thumb="images/audi/red/au3.jpg" name="audi3">
               <div class="thumb-image"> <img src="images/audi/red/au3.jpg" data-imagezoom="true" class="img-responsive" name="audi3"> </div>
            </li>
             <li data-thumb="images/audi/au4.jpg">
               <div class="thumb-image"> <img src="images/audi/au4.jpg" data-imagezoom="true" class="img-responsive"> </div>
            </li>
            <li data-thumb="images/audi/au4a.jpg">
               <div class="thumb-image"> <img src="images/audi/au4a.jpg" data-imagezoom="true" class="img-responsive"> </div>
            </li>
          </ul>
<li>Select a Colour:
    <select name="car-colour" id="car-colour">
    <option value="red">Red</option>
    <option value="white">White</option>
    <option value="black">Black</option>
    <option value="blue">Blue</option>
</select></li>
```